# How to find a group of consecutive leters and check cases with python re

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, uppercase

How can I do a `re.findall()` that looks for a group of 7 letters where the first 3 and the last 3 are all uppercase and the one in the middle is lowercase? So far, I've tried this:

`word1 = "".join(re.findall("[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][a-z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\d{3}","mystring")`]

However, it doesn't output anything.

How can I do this query?

Thanks!

evamvid

Comment: What does print word1 show?

Comment: Your regular expression obviously won't match "mystring". Have you tried it on valid input?

Comment: @diveshpremdeep I did try it on valid input -- however said valid input was too long to put here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this works for me

```
p = re.compile(r"[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}")

word = "".join(re.findall(p, 'udkehtEOajidfEEfjaiERBdEHY alijdfilaOEPvOEG'))
```

**output:**

```
>>> print word
'ERBdEHYOEPvOEG'
```

Of course, if you were actually searching in `"mystring"`, you would naturally get no matches.